# C# exceptions in debug mode vs real

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

I always thought that in Visual Studio and C#, an unhandled exception leads invariably to program termination. Now I know I can continue. Also when the application is running in the debug mode, I can "skip" unhandled exceptions while once the program is deployed (or how is it called when you make an executable?) it will crash it?

Comment: Why would you want to proceed in face of an exceptional situation you can't handle (i.e, an unhandled exception)?

Comment: This isn't true for Winforms or WPF apps.  Or when you have ticked the Thrown checkbox in the Debug + Exceptions dialog.  Document your question better.

Comment: Sorry, I do not want to not unhadle the exception. I would like to only know whether I am right with my assumption.

Comment: @Hans Passant Also however I can proceed in Console app, I will not be able to do it in WinForms or WPF? That is very valuable information, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
  #if DEBUG
   Console.WriteLn("oops")
  #else
   throw
  #endif
}
```

Comment: That should be "throw", not "throw ex" if you want to keep the original stack frame.

Answer (score 0):

I think these articles would be useful for you to read:

> [Exception Handling (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229005.aspx)
>   [Handling and Throwing Exceptions (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b2yeyab.aspx)

It's better to grasp the basics then decide what fits best for you.

Comment: Thanks. I do understand how to handle exception. I am only curious why I can continue in (at least) Console app once an exception occurs. I thought it will terminate.

Answer (score 0):

The exception means something unexpected occured. If the application doesn't know how to respond, it would crash.

The reason we have the constructs like `try catch finally` is to make the application aware of the unforeseen issues and how to react in such cases.

**If you implement exception handling properly**, your application would always run smoothly. It might come to termination, but even that wouldn't be abrupt.